# What is the equivalent in Chinese for the phrase "get laid"?

Tags: word-choice

After my effort, I haven't found the equivalent yet, and it should not be too vulgar, if you have any idea you might share with us.

Answer (score 1):

The only term I could think of is "上床”, which literally means "on the bed". It is used as a metaphor for "get laid" or sex.